# non-blocking forwarding of inbound HTTP request body to outbound HTTP request body with Java

Tags: java, http, asynchronous, pipe, nonblocking

I am looking for a succinct code example that demonstrates non-blocking 'piping' the body of an incoming HTTP POST request to the body of an outgoing HTTP POST request in Java.

There are certainly many examples of non-blocking I/O between files and HTTP requests/responses.  And I assume something might be extrapolated from those examples to the scenario of HTTP incoming request body => HTTP outgoing request body.

Comment: Something like http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Network-Protocol/Asimpleproxyserver.htm ?

Comment: That looks promising. But oddly the code includes starts a thread to copy from input to output, then immediately proceeds to synchronously copy bytes from input to output.

Comment: That’s to pass the response back